# SQL Server query problem

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2000. My table looks like this:

```
stricker    nonstricker    over      status
-----------------------------------------------
sahwag      sachin      0.1        out(sahwag)
kohli        sachin      0.2        not out
```

I want the name of the batsman, like this:

```
------------------
sahwag
sachin
kohli
```

Comment: Which ones are the batsmen? I'm not exactly a cricket fan...

Comment: i dont know how to combine 2 columns in single column multiple rows.

Comment: batsman are...
sahwag
sachin
kohli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want. This will get both the strickers and the nonstrickers from the table:

```
select stricker from myTable
union
select nonstricker from myTable
```

Comment: thank you alex... that is the answer on my question... thanks a lot

Comment: i am trying to vote but i cant vote bcoz of my reputation... sorry friend

Comment: @Pramod: then just mark the answer as accepted (big checkmark below the vote arrows). This will also give you 2 rep points.

Comment: `UNION` will remove duplicates so the `DISTINCT`s in the `SELECT`s themselves are redundant.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you, I forgot about that.